# Ordenar lista encadeada em projeto com padrão MVC

Tags: java, mvc, classificação, lista-encadeada

No meu projeto estou utilizando uma implementação própria de lista encadeada, isto é, não estou usando a lista pronta da API Java. Além disso, a minha implementação é de uma lista genérica, que possui objetos do tipo Object em seus nós, de forma que pode ser utilizada para qualquer tipo de Objeto. Preciso ordenar essa lista encadeada segundo determinado atributo de um tipo específico de objeto. No padrão MVC, qual queria o lugar ideal para essa ordenação? Pensei em realizar a ordenação na própria lista encadeada, mas isso iria "quebrar" a generalidade dela, pois a ordenação que desejo é apenas para um tipo específico de objeto.

Comment: Como a pergunta foi rapidamente fechada(algo que ultimamente tem acontecido muito) vou tentar responder por comentário. Declare na sua implementação um método chamado, por exemplo `sort()`, que receba um [Comparator<T>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) e utilize-o para ordenar a lista. O consumidor da sua classe, quando quiser fazer o *sort*, define o *Comparator* para o seu caso especifico e passa-o ao método `sort()`. Desta forma a implementação da lista encadeada manter-se-ia genérica.

Comment: Vinicius, eu acho que no caso do MVC você está indo um pouco longe demais nos conceitos. Primeiro, MVC não vai ditar em lugar algum como você implementa suas estruturas de dados e outros detalhes de implementação. MVC define apenas o padrão para **alguns** tipos de classes, mais especificamente três tipos. Não existe uma melhor prática geral que vai dizer em que momento ou como você deve ordenar uma lista. Depende das regras do sistema, por exemplo, se essa lista é ordenada apenas em um momento ou se ela deve sempre estar ordenada.

Comment: Além disso, você disse que usou `Object` para aceitar qualquer tipo de objeto, mas usando *Generics* você poderia ter feito o mesmo sem usar `Object` diretamente e mantendo coerência de tipos, assim como é feito na API do Java. Mas ainda ficam algumas perguntas: isso significa que uma mesma instância da lista deva aceita objetos de tipos diferentes? O que deve acontecer se você tiver nessa lista uma mistura de itens incluindo esse *objeto específico* contendo o referido atributo e outros objetos diferentes?

Comment: Se a lista para esse tipo de objeto precisa ser ordenada sempre, mas não outros tipos, então você está precisando de outro tipo de lista. Você pode usar herança e estender a lista original ou criar uma nova implementação polimórfica a partir de uma interface.

Comment: Mas seria mesmo ideal se você postasse seu código, pois tenho certeza que várias pessoas gostariam de ajudar com esse problema. :)